# Port code from python to java using OpenCV

Tags: java, python, opencv

I'm trying to get a java implementation of a python code. The code is related to opencv. The python code works great, but i'm facing some difficulties to get it work with java, I get a *null* exception. I don't know if it's related to the **reshape** functions, or the **get/put** functions.

**Python**:

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,0.02*peri,True)
...
approx=rectify(approx)
...
def rectify(h):
    h = h.reshape((4,2))
    hnew = np.zeros((4,2),dtype = np.float32)

    add = h.sum(1)
    hnew[0] = h[np.argmin(add)]
    hnew[2] = h[np.argmax(add)]

    diff = np.diff(h,axis = 1)
    hnew[1] = h[np.argmin(diff)]
    hnew[3] = h[np.argmax(diff)]

    return hnew
```

**Java**:

```
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newMtx, approx, 0.02 * peri, true);
...
approx = rectify(approx);
...
private Mat rectify(Mat approx) {

    DoubleMatrix ndApproxNew, ndAdd, ndApprox;
    double [] d;
    Mat hnew;

    ndApproxNew = DoubleMatrix.zeros(4, 2);
    hnew = new Mat();

    approx = approx.reshape(0, 4);

    // sum
    d = approx.get(4, 2);
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - heigth: " + approx.height() + " width: " + approx.width());
    ndApprox = new DoubleMatrix(4, 2, d);

    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + ndApprox.getRow(0)); // <- ERROR NULL
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + ndApprox.getRow(1));
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + ndApprox.getRow(2));
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + ndApprox.getRow(3));
```

Comment: If you don't know, debug line by line. Test the functions alone. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out (wasn't easy lol).

My problem is not exactly in that part of the code, the problem relies on I didn't pay attention to the types of values returned.

To be more precise, opencv-python method [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) return:

```
Nx2 numpy array (Python interface)
```

While in my case in [java](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#approxPolyDP(org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20double,%20boolean)) is:

```
MatOfPoint2f approxCurve
```

I realized that my problem was how to manage with a bunch of points (4 in this case) rather than a `reshape` function.

I changed my code to this one and everything is working :D :

```
private MatOfPoint2f rectify(MatOfPoint2f approx) {

    DoubleMatrix ndApproxNew, ndAdd, ndApprox;
    Point[] p;
    double [] d;
    MatOfPoint2f hnew;

    ndApproxNew = DoubleMatrix.zeros(4, 2);
    hnew = new MatOfPoint2f();
    //hnew.put(4, 2, ndZeros.data().asFloat());
    //hnew = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype = np.float32);

    //if (!approx.isContinuous()) approx = approx.clone();
    p = approx.toArray();
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + p[0].x + " " + p[0].y);
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + p[1].x + " " + p[1].y);
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + p[2].x + " " + p[2].y);
    Log.d(TAG, "daily - " + p[3].x + " " + p[3].y);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [Mat::reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#reshape%28int,%20int%29) lets you specify the number of channels of the Mat object.

As you're reshaping the approx variable, you're passing it zero channels. Your problem could be in this line:

```
approx = approx.reshape(0, 4);
```

Comment: I solved my problem, see my answer below. The reshape function in opencv-python is a `numpy` function and not a `Mat` one.

Comment: I was referring to reshape called in your java snippet. This would call OpenCV's java bindings.

Comment: Yes, in some way you are right. But my main problem was with the returned value of `approxPolyDP`.

Comment: Understood. Glad you figured it out.